# Get certain bunch of rows

Tags: linux, sed, awk

I need help in the following: I have this kind of file, named `file-1`

```
1
++++++^^++++
++++++++++++
+++++++++^^^
^^++++++++++

2
++++++++++++
^^^+++++^^^^
^^^^^^^+++++
+++++^^^++^+
```

Now, I would like to print out those part in which the starting number is the same as in another file, named `file-2`.
Let us say that the `file-2` contains the `1` value, so I need to get this output:

```
1
++++++^^++++
++++++++++++
+++++++++^^^
^^++++++++++
```

Can anybody suggest me something?

Comment: Is your delimiter strictly the number?  Your biggest problem here, using strictly awk & sed, is that it is difficult to parse where the thing ends...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ awk -v RS='' 'NR==FNR{split($0, a, /\n/); next}; $1 in a' file-{2,1}
1
++++++^^++++
++++++++++++
+++++++++^^^
^^++++++++++
```

`file-2` contains indexes line by line:

```
1
3
5
```

#### Explaination:

- **`RS=''`** tell `awk` to read multi-line records
- **`NR==FNR`** read `file-2` as one-line, so we should `split` by `\n`, and save result in array `a`
- **`next`** skip rest commands, ready to read `file-1`
- **`$1 in a`** test whether `file-1`'s 1st column in array `a`
- **`file-{2,1}`** we should read `file-2` first to get all indexes

Comment: clever usage of split! handle different 'RS' needs

Comment: A bit too clever. Your program iterates over the array indices, not the values. If the input file is not already sorted and the numbers are not of the form 1,2,3 etc. this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's|.*|/^&$/,/^$/p|' file2 | sed -nf - file1
1
++++++^^++++
++++++++++++
+++++++++^^^
^^++++++++++
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU-awk, you can try something like this -

```
gawk 'NR==FNR {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i];next} ($1 in a)' RS='\n\n' file-{2,1}
```

> #### Explanation:
>
> 1. We set the Record Separator to `\n\n` using the built-in RS variables.
> 2. We use a for loop and store values in our `file-2` in an array. This will identify which records you want to pull out from `file-1`.
> 3. We check the first column of `file-1`. If it is present in the array we print that record. Else we dont.

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file-1
1
++++++^^++++
++++++++++++
+++++++++^^^
^^++++++++++

2
++++++++++++
^^^+++++^^^^
^^^^^^^+++++
+++++^^^++^+

[jaypal:~/Temp] cat file-2
1
3
4

[jaypal:~/Temp] gawk 'NR==FNR {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i];next} ($1 in a)' RS='\n\n' file-{2,1}
1
++++++^^++++
++++++++++++
+++++++++^^^
^^++++++++++
```